# How do I capture "Find" command in vscode custom editor extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a custom editor document extension for vscode and I want to have a custom find widget that will suit what I'm doing in my document. How do I capture the find event and execute some code. I tried registering a command for "actions.find" but this made other tabs not able to use the find command. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: create a WebviewView and construct your own Find widget.

Comment: Yes but how do I activate with say ctrl + F?

Comment: Can you re-emit the find command (executeCommand(`actions.find`) if you are not in your custom editor?

Comment: create your own ViewContainer show it with a key combo of your choice, you can remove the keybinding for Ctrl+F and hook it up to something else, you can use a `when` on the keybinding and set a context variable when focus is in your custom editor